# Показ страницы после полной загрузки

Tags: html

Доброго всем дня

Есть страница, которая работает и к ней претензий нет. При открытии страницы фотки начинают загружаться. Как сделать, что бы страница не открывалась до тех пор, пока все фото не будут загружены?

т.е. что бы человек не видел как там все грузится, а увидел уже загруженную страницу

Comment: Вы уверенны в своем желании?

Если фотографий много и они не по 5кб, то загрузка может занять пару секунд. А если еще и медленный интернет то и пару-тройку секунд. 

Когда человек видит процесс загрузки он понимает, что все идет хорошо и страница грузится. Если же при попытке зайти на страницу он будет видеть просто чистый лист в течении тех самых 5-8 секунд, он просто закроет страницу и решит - сайт не работает.

% отказов станет очень большим. Это плохая практика не показывать страницу и просто ждать пока все фотографии загрузятся.

Comment: уверен. я в курсе про задержку и какой она может быть. мне нужно то для одной спец. страницы. так что все будет нормально

Answer (score 1, accepted):

почитать про событие onload ,также как плюс можеш посмотреть lazy-load.